# Limit string input in batch cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I can't get my head around how to solve this. Got the following code:

```
:userinfo
set U=U
set /p EmployeeID=Please enter Employee ID:
for /f "tokens=1* delims=0123456789XC" %%a in ("A0%EmployeeID:"=%") do if not "%%b"=="" echo Only numbers, except X and C, case sensitive! && goto userinfo
```

It works fine but I want to limit the input characters to 7 characters. Means it needs to be 7 characters - not maximum 7.

I tried with `if not "!EmployeeID:~7! == "" echo 7 characters required. & goto userinfo` but this doesn't work.

I'm sure this is a 'simple' thing to fix..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? is there an error message, or is the result different from what you expect? There is a closing quote missing in `if not "!EmployeeID:~7! == ""`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `if "!EmployeeID:~7!"==""` evaluates to *true* in case the string is not longer than 7 characters (supposing [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion) is enabled due to `!!`).

To solve your task, simply apply a second condition: `if not "!EmployeeID:~6!"==""` is *true* in case the string is at least 7 characters long.

Then concatenate both conditions:

```
:userinfo
set /p EmployeeID="Please enter Employee ID: "
for /f "tokens=1* delims=0123456789XC" %%a in ("A0%EmployeeID:"=%") do (
    if not "%%b"=="" (
        echo Only numbers, except X and C, case sensitive^^!
        goto userinfo
    )
)
if "!EmployeeID:~7!"=="" if not "!EmployeeID:~6!"=="" (
    rem Both conditions fulfilled, so continue
    goto continue
) else (
    echo 7 characters required.
    goto userinfo
)
:continue
```

---

An alternative approach is to use `findstr`, which you can achieve checks against both character set and length with, like this:

```
:userinfo
set "EmployeeID="
set /p EmployeeID="Please enter Employee ID: "
echo(!EmployeeID!|findstr "^[0-9XC][0-9XC][0-9XC][0-9XC][0-9XC][0-9XC][0-9XC]$" 2> nul || (
    echo 7 characters, only numbers, X and C, case-sensitive^^!
    goto :userinfo
)
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I used your 2nd code snippet and changed it so only the first character can be X or C which is how we wanted it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Works great in Windows 7 - however not in WinPE. It just exit; doesn't matter what I enter (right or wrong). Any idea?

Comment: Type `where findstr` and see if there is `findstr` available; if not, I guess you have to switch to the first variant...

Comment: You are the man! Thanks! I have just copied findstr.exe from Windows to WinPE and it works great!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly different approach:

```
SET /P EmployeeID=Please enter Employee ID:
IF %EmployeeID:~-7% NEQ %EmployeeID% GOTO :userinfo
ECHO(%EmployeeID%|FINDSTR/R "[^0-9XC]" && (
    ECHO(Only numbers, except X and C, case sensitive!
    GOTO :userinfo)
```

If your intention is not to limit but to restrict then you could just check if there is an eight character or a seventh character:

```dos
:userinfo
SET /P EmployeeID=Please enter Employee ID:
IF "%EmployeeID:~6,1%" NEQ "" (IF "%EmployeeID:~7,1%" EQU "" (
        ECHO(%EmployeeID%|FINDSTR/R "[^0-9XC]" && (
            ECHO(Only numbers, except X and C, case sensitive!
        ) || (GOTO :continue)))
GOTO :userinfo
:continue
SET U=U
```

Comment: Please appreciate the response I provided by marking it appropriately as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This different approach have several advantages:

- It only allows to enter the proper characters; any other character is rejected and the bell is sound. It even accept uppercase "X" or "C" letters *only*!
- It *automatically* ends when 7 characters had been input, so there is no way to enter less or more characters.
- You may even could define a format for the employee ID with some additional code; for example: 4 digits + letter "X" or "C" + 2 digits.

The only disadvantage of this method is that there is no way to delete the last character, but this is possible with additional code using another key, *not* the BS usual key.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "chars= 0123456789XC"
set "ID="
echo Enter digits 0-9 and *uppercase* "X" or "C" letters only^^!
set /P "=Please enter Employee ID: " < NUL
for /L %%i in (1,1,7) do (
   choice /C %chars% /N /CS > NUL
   for %%e in (!errorlevel!) do set "char=!chars:~%%e,1!"
   set /P "=!char!" < NUL
   set "ID=!ID!!char!"
)
echo/
echo/
echo Employe ID: %ID%
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this one. Funny though, I can't use the backspace key :-) It just beeps if I wrote a mistake.